# Hartman-Grobman Theorem

Tags: dynamical-systems

The H-G Theorem say that if the singularity is hyperbolic (all the eigenvalues of the "linearized" system have a not null real part), then in an environment of the singularity the phase portrait is topologically conjugated to that of the linearized system.

> In all the books I have read, one of the hypotheses assumed in the proof of this theorem is that the singular point is at the origin.
>   However, intuition tells me that the Theorem also works with singularities that are not at the origin. Is this so?

Comment: Yes, it holds also in other points. If your system is expressed in the variables $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ and the stationary point is $(\bar x_1,\bar x_2,\ldots,\bar x_n)$, then you just need to rewrite the system in the "local" variables $(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n)=(x_1-\bar x_1,x_2-\bar x_2,\ldots,x_n-\bar x_n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, certainly, since you can just apply the simple change of variables $y=x-x^*$ to move the singular point from $x=x^*$ to $y=0$.